# TimePickerDialog custom theme

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio

I'm developping an Android app and right now I'm having an issue with a part of my UI: a TimePickerDialog. I'd like the top part of the Dialog to be orange instead of the classic

I know that I could create a custome theme, but my boss want it developp in 4.0 (API 15) so that it covers almost every device.. I don't know how to set a color with using settings covered by API 21 and up..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TimePickerDialog appearance is very different in the API levels you are testing on. The biggest redesign was probably made in Lollipop (API 21), where the default dialog has a totally different (circular) look:

[image]

If you are testing on API21+, you are probably seeing this one. The background color AFAIK can be changed by tweaking the `android:color*` attributes in your theme. I'm not sure which one (could be `android:colorAccent`, `android:colorPrimary`...), but it is easy to determine.

However, since you are going to deploy down to API 15, and default time picker there is quite different, I would recommend using an external library to give each user the same look and feel of Lollipop.

The most used is probably [this one](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker), and allows you to style the dialog in terms of colors and much more.

Comment: Great! Thank you! My boss sometimes fears to use public libraries put still, I'll use this one, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

API>=21:You can define `<item name="colorPrimary">xxxx</item>` in your style of theme

API<21:Use libary for example [material libary](https://github.com/rey5137/material)